# Get all the "*.xxx" files in the document directory in Swift 4

Tags: swift4, nsfilemanager

I'm looking over the `NSFileManager.h` dox in Swift 4 and it seems it changed since I last used it (for the better!).

I'm wondering if `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys`, `url` or `enumeratorAtURL:includingPropertiesForKeys` provides a way to enumerate over a specific type of file, in my case images?

I've looked at the many Swift 2 answers and they all suggest looping and examining the name, and I want to be sure they haven't "fixed" this and I'm simply confused by the API?

Comment: `contentsOfDirectoryAtURL` returns `[URL]`. You can `filter` the URLs by their `pathExtension` z.B. `.filter {$0.pathExtension == "xxx"}`

Comment: Perfect! If you make that an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just `filter` the returned `URLs` by `pathExtension`

```
do {
    let docs = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: .documentsDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options:  .skipsHiddenFiles)
    let images = docs.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "xxx" }
    print(images)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```